# How to import an obj file containing RGB data at unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, modeling

The document was translated into Google Translator.

I have an obj file containing vertex position and the RGB data for that vertex. The corresponding obj file code is as follows.

**obj.file :**

```
v 27.795225 -8.144943 -10.956295 0.647059 0.313726 0.290196

v 27.830965 -8.110074 -11.030095 0.629412 0.309804 0.290196

v 27.762598 -8.133816 -11.034611 0.647059 0.313726 0.290196

v 27.847612 -8.126033 -10.965885 0.611765 0.305882 0.290196

v 27.847620 -8.140801 -10.931058 0.631373 0.317647 0.294118

v 27.891783 -8.117332 -11.027543 0.611765 0.305882 0.290196

....
```

I imported the obj file to Unity, but the modelling did not have any color.

How can I apply color data to my model.

Comment: you can use the [Particle - Standard shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-StandardParticleShaders.html) which has vertex color support. Or use any other [Vertex Shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a vertex color shader to your object to see the color data. but using unity standard shader will not work reading your color information on the object.

Comment: select your material and change the shader type to vertex color shader